# Calculate the bounds of a segment of a background-image in Javascript

Tags: javascript, css, background-image

Is there a way to calculate the rectangle bounds of a segment of a background-image (e.g a red circle on the white background of the image) which is scaled by background-size: cover, even if it has a negativ value and is out of the mobile device viewport?
Another solution would be to pin a x/y coordinate on the background picture position.

[image: bounds]

CSS:

```
  .background{
     position: absolute;
     width: 100%;
     height:100%;
     background: url('img.png') no-repeat;
     background-size: cover;
     background-position: 50% 0;
```

}

Here is the pen i made.
You have to scale the browser to see the behaviour of the image-

http://codepen.io/kmpkt/pen/MbzxvM

Does anyone have an idea to solve this problem?

Comment: [_What_ problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378)

Comment: _"Another solution would be to pin a x/y coordinate on the background picture position"_ - I can only _guess_ that _maybe_ the behavior of background-position set in percentages _might_ be what you _could_ be looking for ...

Comment: The ball is not centred in the png image, which has natural width/height of 300 x 800 px. Will you be putting details of where the ROI (region of interest) is located in the png image into the script? Is the problem more than finding the size of the absolute element and reproducing (or determining) CSS calculations?

Comment: Hi Traktor53, yes i would like to put the bounds (x,y,width,height) of the ROI into my script and would like to calculate the transformation due to the scaling and position change of the ROI. And the problem is more then finding the size and position of the element.

Comment: Suggest giving the absolutely positioned element an `id` attribute, `document.getElementById()` to get the element object, and [`element.getBoundingClientRect()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) to get its dimensions in the viewport. I can see what the desired effect and required information is, but havn't continued into writing code.

Comment: A quick clarification: is the background fixed in relation to the viewport and intended to cover it?

Comment: I updated my codepen, maybe now it will become more clean what i intend to do.

Comment: The background image is intend to cover the viewport. Due to the many different device resolutions the background image and the ROI is not always on the same position and has the same size. So i need to know exactly where the bounds of the ROI is, so i can align my content divs in the middle of the ROI.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130748/discussion-between-traktor53-and-faumiller).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### CSS `background-size: cover`

A `background-size` value of `cover;` applied to an element causes background images to be scaled, keeping their aspect ratio, so that the scaled image matches either the width or height of the element and is not smaller than it.

The scaling value required can be found by comparing aspect ratios of the element and background image, using a `width/height` quotient in the comparison.

If the element's aspect ratio is higher than the image's, the image is widened or narrowed to fit using a scaling value of:

```
    scale = element.width/image.width; // the element is more "landscape" than the image
```

If not the image is heightened or shortened to fit using a scaling value of:

```
   scale = element.height/image.height; // the element is more "portrait" then the image.
```

Note both width and height of the background image are scaled using the same factor.

*Dimensions and offsets for a region of interest (ROI) within the background image must be scaled by the same scaling factor determined above.*

#### CSS `background-position: 50% 0;`

I understand this makes no change to the y position of the background, but centers the background along the x-axis if it needs to be clipped on either side. Without x-axis clipping a scaled background image is centered by definition.

If the scaled image width is greater than the element's, the background needs to be moved left by half the difference:

```
xTranslation = (elementWidth - scaledImageWidth) / 2  // scaledImageWidth > elementWidth,
```

If not, no translation is required:

```
xTranslation = 0 // scaled image width == element width
```

*A previously scaled x-axis offset for a region of interest within the background image needs to have the x translation determined above applied to it.*

#### Finding the size of the backgrounded element.

[`element.getClientBorderRect()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect)

returns an object containing width and height values for the element.

**Avoid** using `document.clientWidth` and `document.clientHeight` to obtain the dimensions of the viewport. `clientHeight` is returned with a maximum value of the the height of the body element. This can be less than the height of the viewport.